# How Properly Call .Net Using Go

Tags: c#, .net, go, wmi

I am trying to run a .Net code on Power Shell from inside a Go code using `"os/exec"` import as follows:

**.Net code**

```
    using System.Management;
    public static List<string> GetAllConnectedCameras()
    {
        var cameraNames = new List<string>();
        using (var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPEntity WHERE (PNPClass = 'Image' OR PNPClass = 'Camera')"))
        {
            foreach (var device in searcher.Get())
            {
                cameraNames.Add(device["Caption"].ToString());
            }
        }

        return cameraNames;
    }
```

**Go code**

```
package main

import (
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {

    _ = exec.Command("PowerShell", "-Command", "Add-Type", "-AssemblyName", "using System.Management; public static List<string> GetAllConnectedCameras(){var cameraNames = new List<string>();using (var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(\"SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPEntity WHERE (PNPClass = 'Image' OR PNPClass = 'Camera')\")){foreach (var device in searcher.Get()){cameraNames.Add(device[\"Caption\"].ToString());}}return cameraNames;}Console.WriteLine(GetAllConnectedCameras());")

}
```

I also added at the end of `exec.Command` `Console.WriteLine(GetAllConnectedCameras());`aimimg to print the results. The output is completely empty.

Previously I tried to get the results saving the `exec.Command` into a variable:

```
results := exec.Command("PowerShell", "-Command", "Add-Type", "-AssemblyName", "using System.Management; public static List<string> GetAllConnectedCameras(){var cameraNames = new List<string>();using (var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(\"SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPEntity WHERE (PNPClass = 'Image' OR PNPClass = 'Camera')\")){foreach (var device in searcher.Get()){cameraNames.Add(device[\"Caption\"].ToString());}}return cameraNames;})

fmt.Println(results)
```

But this only have printed the commands. I also tried without the flags `"-Command", "Add-Type", "-AssemblyName"`, but he same empty output occured.

I also tried insert at the end `.CombinedOutput()`:

```
package main

import (
    "os/exec"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {

    a, _ := exec.Command("PowerShell", "-Command", "Add-Type", "-AssemblyName", "using System.Management; public static List<string> GetAllConnectedCameras(){var cameraNames = new List<string>();using (var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(\"SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPEntity WHERE (PNPClass = 'Image' OR PNPClass = 'Camera')\")){foreach (var device in searcher.Get()){cameraNames.Add(device[\"Caption\"].ToString());}}return cameraNames;}Console.WriteLine(GetAllConnectedCameras());").CombinedOutput()
    
fmt.Println(a)

}
```

But I got a array of bytes that when translated to string are messages of erros.

Comment: Why not just use `Get-WMIObject` directly in Powershell?

Comment: @gunr2171 I have an integrated webcam (device 0), when I call `Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_PnPEntity | Where-Object {$_.PNPClass -Match "Image"} | Select-Object Name` nothing appears to me, for this reason I am trying other solutions to get a list of all camera devices.

Comment: You are **not** calling .Net code from Go, you are trying to launch a process. Specifically, you are lauching a powershell process to run the .NET code and doing nothing with it, that's why you are seeing nothing. It's very important to get this difference right, because they mean very different things.

About your approach, you are not calling  the `Output` or `CombinedOutput` method. The `Command` function does not run the command, just creates one.

Comment: I have updated my post with the `.CombinedOutput()`, nevertheless I still got errors. Could you give me a more complete answer? I am not .Net dev, I am rustically trying to adapt it to my go code, if you could show me how to proper do it will be very helpful.